# Binding Set to form with ListItems in Wicket

Tags: java, apache, wicket

So I work with Apache Wicket and I have the Model class with the attributes:

```
private String name;
private Set<Details> details;
```

where Details class is

```
private String detailsName;
private DetailsEnum detailsEnum;
```

and DetailsEnum is enum { SOME, MORE, MOST }.
I have problem with a Set of Details. There is the ListView but it works with a List, not a Set. 
I need to have the form like this:

name:[ *examplemodelname* ]

*detailsName*: [here dropDownChoice with this enum]

*detailsName*: [here dropDownChoice with this enum]

*detailsName*: [here dropDownChoice with this enum]

But I don't know how to bind Set in a proper way.

Comment: You can change set to list and pass it to listview

Answer (score 0):

Do you want create 3 dropDownChoice, but in your model you have set of Details. Can't be sure that in set exist 3 objects.

I would change Model:

```
private String name;
private DetailsEnum detail1;
private DetailsEnum detail2;
private DetailsEnum detail3;
```

And in your form with CompundPropertyModel of your model:

```
form.add(new DropDownChoice<>("detail1"), Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.SOME, DetailsEnum.MORE, DetailsEnum.MOST), new Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.values()));
form.add(new DropDownChoice<>("detail2"), Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.SOME, DetailsEnum.MORE, DetailsEnum.MOST), new Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.values()));
form.add(new DropDownChoice<>("detail3"), Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.SOME, DetailsEnum.MORE, DetailsEnum.MOST), new Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.values()));
```

You also can rewrite the displayed value, except of `new Arrays.asList(DetailsEnum.values())` write `new EnumChoiceRenderer<DetailsEnum>(this)` and define something like this in property file:

```
DetailsEnum.SOME=Some
DetailsEnum.MORE=More
DetailsEnum.MOST=Most
```

Comment: I didn't mean this. I meant set of Details but I put only few for example. I fixed this problem by this: `IModel listModel = new PropertyModel(layerDetails, "attributes") {
 

   public Object getObject() {
    
    return new ArrayList((Set) super.getObject());
   }
  };`   and creating Listview from this listModel where I override populateItem method